# Add-Computer fails by not finding the domain

Tags: powershell, dns

I'm working an a script to autoconfigure my VMs. The idea is, that the VM automatic configures its netadapter and the joins a domain via default credentials. It's supposed to work with 2012r2, so PoShv4 is in use.

It works perfect until it comes to the point of working with `Add-Computer`

```
$vmName = (Get-ItemProperty –path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Virtual Machine\Guest\Parameters').VirtualMachineName
$vmName = $vmName -replace '\w+\s+(.+)' , '$1'

$ip = $vmName -replace '\D+(\d+)' , '$1'

switch -Regex ($vmName) {
    'dc' {$Ip = '10.18.0.{0}0' -f $ip}
    'srv' {$Ip = '10.18.1.{0}0' -f $ip}
    'CL' {$Ip = '10.18.2.{0}0' -f $ip}
}

#Configure IP-Settings
$netadapter = Get-NetAdapter -Name Ethernet

$netadapter | Set-NetIPInterface -DHCP Disabled | Out-Null

$netadapter | New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress $ip -PrefixLength 16 -DefaultGateway 10.18.0.10 | Out-Null

Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias Ethernet -ServerAddresses 10.18.0.10 | Out-Null

#Create Credentials for Domainjoin
$username = 'domain\administrator'
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'Passw0rd' -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

#Check if Domainjoin possible
if ($vmName -eq 'DC1') 
{
    Install-WindowsFeature AD-Domain-services -IncludeAllSubFeature -IncludeManagementTools
    Rename-Computer $vmName -Restart
}
elseif ($vmName -match 'DC')
{
    Install-WindowsFeature AD-Domain-services -IncludeAllSubFeature -IncludeManagementTools
 -DomainCredential $cred -NewName $vmName -Restart
}
else 
{
    $null = [net.dns]::Resolve('domain.tld')
    Add-Computer -DomainName 'domain.tld' -DomainCredential $cred -NewName $vmName -Restart -Server 'dc1.domain.tld'
}
```

`Add-Computer` fails with the following error:

```
Add-Computer : Der angegebene Servername "dc1.domain.tld" kann nicht aufgelöst werden.
In C:\VMAutoConfig.ps1:42 Zeichen:5
+     Add-Computer -DomainName 'domain.tld' -DomainCredential $cred -NewName $ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (dc1.domain.tld:String) [Add-Computer], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddressResolutionException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddComputerCommand
```

Any known issues with that?

Timedelay of up to 5 secs between netadapter config and `Add-Computer` does not help at all.

If I run the script a second time, everthing's ok and works.

Comment: Please show the exact error message. What is your PowerShell version? Did you try without `-Server` and/or with `-Server domain\DC1`?

Comment: Error when using `-server`: Cannot resolve servername "dc1.domain.tld" (AddressResolutionException)

[net.dns] didnt throw an error and was able to resolve the domainname via DC1 as DNS-Server. 

Tried on two vms to get the error, while the first vm just run without errors.

Comment: Please put the complete error message in your question. Please answer the other questions as well. Also add the code that configures the network interface(s). You may obfuscate IP addresses and domain names, as long as you do it in a consistent way.